# windows server 2008 port forwarding to VM

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, nat, port-forwarding, vmware-workstation

I have Windows server 2008 r2 as a server and few virtual machines inside VMware Workstation. This VM's must receive connections from outside servers on port 8899. I enabled port forwarding on VMware NAT and did some tricks on win server which i found in google but it didnt helped :(

If anyone know what to do or where to find it, it will be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you're more specific about what you did with the VMWare NAT and what tricks you already tried and any results.  The more specific you are, the more likely you are to get help.

Answer (score 0):

Set the network adapter for bridged instead of NAT in VMware. Then you should be able to port forward to the IP of the vm.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but its not working  - when i tried ti switch NIC type to bridged VM lose connection at all.